# Does it really end with 'Magician's End'?

Tags: riftwar-cycle, raymond-e-feist

I'm a big fan of the Raymond E. Feist's *Riftwar Cycle*. The story appears to be wrapped up with the novel *Magician's End*, which was published in 2013. However, there are plenty of plot hooks (young Pug as Magnus's apprentice, the future of the Kingdom of the Idle, etc.) that seem ripe for future novels.

Has there been any *official word* from Feist or his editors/publishers about any future plans to return to the Riftwar setting?

Comment: I fail to see how, in its current form this question can be considered opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raymond Feist's [official website](http://www.crydee.com/raymond-feist/book-synopsis/magicians-end) indicates that the book "Magician's End" will be the *last* novel set in the Riftwar universe. While this doesn't negate the fact that Feist may simply change his mind, since it was announced in 2008 (and since no further works seem to be in the pipeline), I personally wouldn't expect to see many new works set in Midkemia.

> "This book has yet to be released. **It will be the final book in The
>   Riftwar Cycle.**
>
> The title was announced by Raymond E. Feist on the Feistfans-l Mailing
>   List on 19 February 2008"

In a [more recent interview](http://jamiespages.org/tag/empire-trilogy/) Feist indicated that he was primarily writing the Riftwar books due to a contractual obligation rather than any special love for the series and that he's much more interested in his new trilogy than revisiting the Midkemia novels.

> *It has been a year since the series concluded, but at this stage Feist does not miss Midkemia, nor have any immediate intention of
>   returning. “Not right now”, he says. “I can always go back should the
>   urge strike, which is probably why I don’t, but anything is
>   possible.”*